# Create 2d array in servlet and do addition

Tags: java, html, arrays, servlets

I am new to working with servlets and working on a project for school. I am trying to read input from an html file. The input is in this format: 100 101 102;200 201 202;300 301 302 and trying to make a 2d array where the semicolon separates rows. I currently have the following:

```
    String numbers = request.getParameter("arrayA");
    int array1[][] = new int[numbers.length()][];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length(); i++) {
        String[] line = numbers.split(";");
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length(); j++) {
            array1[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(line[j]);
        }
    }
```

I get this when i try to use String[] line = numbers.split(";");

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100 101 102"
```

Stuck on finding whats wrong. Any help would be great! Thanks!

EDIT: I now have the following code trying to do what the answer below suggested but get: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[Ljava.lang.String;@10c105e"

```
   String numbers = request.getParameter("arrayA");
    int array1[][] = new int[numbers.length()][];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length(); i++) {
        String[] line = numbers.split(";");
        String temp = line.toString();
        String[] num = temp.split(" ");
        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length(); j++) {
            array1[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(num[j]);
        }
    }
```

Not sure if its just my logic or what

Answer (score 0):

Because `100 101 102` is not a valid Integer.

When you try to turn a invalid number format into a int type `Integer.parseInt(line[j])`, it return the error.

---

Update

you should use those methods correctly.

```
    String numbers = "100 101 102;200 201 202;300 301 302";
    int array1[][] = new int[numbers.length()][];
    //why use number.length?  number.length is the String's length
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length(); i++) 
    {
        String[] line = numbers.split(";");
        //line[0]="100 101 102" , line[1]="200 201 202" , line[2]="300 301 302"
        String temp = line.toString();    
        //Have you ever print this?
        String[] num = temp.split(" ");   
        //you got wrong temp then get wrong num.

        for (int j = 0; j < numbers.length(); j++) 
        {
            array1[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(num[j]);
        }
        //cannout figure out why use numbers.length()
    }
```

Comment: how would i fix this? split it by spaces or what? @TomN

Comment: Yes, you can split it again by spaces. String will become `100` , `101` and `102`. Then the formations are fine.

Comment: ' line = numbers.split(" ");' after i split by semicolon gives me null pointer exception

Comment: why you split numbers again? split line[] into another String array.